# Initial lag for a cell with a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uitextview, instruments

**Current Setup**

I have a custom cell, loaded from a xib, where most of its space is covered by UITextview. Also that cell may have a few textviews. And there are few more elements (one UIView + 2 UILabels) inside of this cell.

**The Problem**

I tried removing all those views and lag stays even if I have only one textview. Also, the lag is happening only for the first time. Later on, when I scroll down, and run into another cell with a textview in it, the lag doesn't happen at all.

**Additional Info**

The thing with this custom cell is that a textview is added to a `UIStackView`. At the beginning, a stackview is empty, because I don't know (at development time) how many textviews may/should be there.

I am aware that this is another thing that might affect on performance, but I have solved it ( I guess as best as it could) by checking how many textviews are already found in stackview's `arrangedSubviews` array when dequeuing a cell, and based on that info, I just add or hide views appropriately (rather than to destroying, and re-creating a required number of textviews each time).

I have tried using Instruments, but I didn't noticed that any of my classes take up CPU time, but rather some `UIKit` method calls that are called by the framework internally are the cause of this... If needed, I can post a screenshot, but I guess this is not relevant because those seem to be the usual system & framework calls. Plus I am testing on iPad 2 :D so maybe that is a thing (I have to optimize an app for slow devices).

Still, I guess I can optimize this somehow?

The MyCell class is rather simple (pseudo code):

```
class MyCell:UITableViewCell{

    func configure(data:SomeData){

        self.addOrHideViewsIfNeeded()
    }

    private func addOrHideViewsIfNeeded(){
        //here, I check if stackview.arrangedSubviews has, and how many subviews are there, and
        //add / hide them appropriately, means if I have to add them, I load them from the nib, otherwise, I reuse views from by adding them/removing them from a pool.
    }
}
```

Also the lag is more noticealbe in Debug version in compare to Release version, which make sense, but it is still noticeable.

Comment: Oh yeah, text views are initially loaded from a nib and use System font  rather than custom font.

Comment: I don't think this is due to `UITextView`. From my experience, and from what can be read online, `UIStackView`, while being really convenient, has poor performance. Complicated AutoLayout rules also take some time to calculate. In our app, we had ~20 components on a cell, and a lot of constraints, and there was visible lag, even on newer devices. We solved this by switching to manual layouting - we calculate the frames ourselves in cells `layoutSubviews`. While I realise this may mean a lot of changes in your code, it might be worth a try.

Comment: @Losiowaty Well the thing is, I have different type of cells in my table view. Every cell has uistackview inside it. Only cell with a text view lags for the first time. But as I said, lags comes from Mac's hdd, while attached on debugger. When an application is not attached through the usb cable, there is no (visible) lag. But yeah, stack view is not that performant.

Comment: I had a lagging animated UIImageView in a cell and did draw an invisible zero row to do preloading. Perhaps similar approach would work in your case.

Comment: @Kamil.S I did something like that earlier (iirc in viewDidLoad:) and it worked, but I thought I might get without preloading and wanted to figure out why the lag is happening... But I wonder what exactly did you have in mind (eg. in which method, sync/async etc...)? Can you write an example ? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a sketch of my idea to do the preloading in an invisible from user perspective tableview row zero.

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    static var initiallyPreloaded : Bool = false

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if !MyCell.initiallyPreloaded {
//Do the initial preloading setup by adding UITextView to self.contentView
            MyCell.initiallyPreloaded = true
        } else {
//Setup the regular cell content otherwise
        }
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell: MyCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier") as! MyCell?
        if cell == nil {
            cell = MyCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier")
        }
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
//Display the initial cell in unnoticeable to user way (start with hidden/alpha zero)
//For this zero-th row the initial preloading should happen
        }
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: I just had to add `UITextView` at initialization of a cell, rather than to do that after cell's initialization. Also I had to do this in `awakeFromNib()` because I am accessing cells outlets ( text view is not added actually to the `contentView`, but rather to the stackview as I mentioned in my question). So, no invisible cells have been needed. Anyway, you helped me to find a solution for the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear. In my case I was starting an invisible animation which normally would lag on 1st appearance. And correct `awakeFromNib()` is a way to go if you're using interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to check if you are re-using the cells or not.

You can reuse it as below:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NAIndexPath *) indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Mycell";

cell = [tableView dequeueCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
    cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
 }
```

Comment: I have registered nibs using the tableview's `register(_ nib:UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier:String)` in my `viewDidLoad()`. Also, I put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAt` delegate method, and cell is not nil, but rather dequeued correctly. The thing is, that the lag happens only when I am on Debugger. I was mistaken and there is no lag when I build an run an app on an actual device in Release mode without keeping it attached to a debuger. But you have my upvote because your answer in general might be helpful.